# wxPython Menu - deselect all Radio Buttons (wx.RADIO_ITEM)

Tags: python, python-2.7, radio-button, wxpython, menuitem

im working on my first wxpython app. Its a GUI for a comandline utility and needs the connection to a samba share. Now i want to add a server selection to the menu as radio buttons.
Im using ConfigParser for a settings ini file which also holds the configuration for the default server as well as 
the server it should connect.

Now i want to deselect all radio buttons if no default server is selected and the program didnt connect at
startup.

Here is my Code for adding the RADIO_ITEMS to the menu:
(I know this could probably be done much better but im still learning and im glad it works, any recommendatiosn are welcome)

```
# Create a List to be used as variables
for i in range(1,7):
    list.append('radiobutton{}'.format(str(i)))
# Append the RadioButtons
for i in range(1,7):
    num = str(i)
    # Load Sections of ini (every server has its own section, up to 6 are allowed)
    config_sec = Config.sections()
    if filter(lambda x: 'Server{}'.format(num) in x, config_sec):
        name = LoadConfig("Server{}".format(num))['connection name']
        list[i] = wx.MenuItem(self.wpkg_server, 400+i, name, 'Connect to Server: {} ?'.format(name), kind=wx.ITEM_RADIO)
        self.wpkg_server.AppendItem(list[i])
        # Get Default server setting from ini
        default_server = LoadConfig("Options")['default server']
        # Try if default_server is a valid number that can be converted to int
        try:
            int(default_server)
        except ValueError:
            # This is the part not working, if there is no default server set i want to uncheck
            # deselect all added items but with no luck.
            # the first item is always selected if no default server was set
            list[i].Check(False)
        else:
            if i == int(default_server):
                # Selecting the correct radio button if it is the default server works fine
                list[i].Check(True)
                self.statusbar.SetStatusText('Connected to Server: {}!'.format(name))
```

Answer (score 1):

You are right Sonic, it appears that you must have something checked in menu RadioItems, so adding a dummy is a practical way around the issue but there is an easier way of setting the selected item. e.g.
    b_m = wx.Menu()
    b_m.AppendRadioItem(1, "Full Screen On")
    b_m.AppendRadioItem(2, "Full Screen Off")
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnFScrOn, id=1)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_MENU, self.OnFScrOff, id=2)
    b_m.Check(2,True)

The last line sets menu item id 2 to True

I too would expect an index problem with 
`list[i].Check(False)`
as Joran mentioned above

Answer (score 0):

```
[menu.Check(False) for menu in my_list]
```

don't use list as your variable name, also I would expect you to get an IndexError with this code ....

Comment: This results in: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'Check'` the code works fine, didnt notice any errors. Check(True) also works but Check(False) seems to be ignored.  What would be the better solution to create create the variables for the menuitems?

Comment: THanks,its seems to be not possible to deactivate all radio buttons in a menu. My solution, add another (Not connected) and then Disable this one. It can still be checked in a function but its greyed out so the user cant interact with it.